# Meaning of euclidean distance matrix's rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is well known that in dimension $m$, an Euclidean distance matrix has rank less than or equal to m+2. [Wiki also knows about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance_matrix)

Also another known fact is added there:

> If the points $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}$ are in general position, the
>   rank is exactly $min(n, m + 2)$.

But wherever I read about it, the opposite statement is never mentioned, seemingly being wrong. So, let's say I've got a $n \times n$ Euclidean distance matrix and it *really has got* the rank equal to $m+2$.

What would it mean? Are there any other definite opportunities for that matrix other than to contain points in general position? The reverse statement has not been proven or there *are* more options (possibly undiscovered yet)?

So, briefly speaking, what conclusions can be made from the fact that the Euclidean distance matrix has it's rank equal to $space \ dimension + 2$?

Comment: "So, let's say I've got a × Euclidean matrix and it really has got the rank equal to +2." Should one of the $n$s in $n \times n$ be an $m$? Or are you just asking "if I have $n$ points in $n$-space, and the rank of the matrix whose columns are the coordinates of those points is some number $r$ (which I've written as $m+2$), can I say anything useful about the points?" The answer is "yes," of course, but I'd like to be sure that it's what you're asking.

Comment: Oh, you've got it right. It is about something like "there are $n$ points, I build a square euclidean matrix of dimension $n$ ($n \times n$ matrix of squared distances), it's rank is exactly 5 in 3-dimentional space (let's call it $r$). What does it mean?".

Comment: Uh...that doesn't make sense, No $3 \times 3$ matrix can have rank $5%. My earlier comment was slightly wrong, in the sense that the entries of the matrix should have been distances (I guess!) rather than coordinates.

Comment: Nooo, my explanation made it worse((. Sorry, let me start from the beginning and let me be exact, not abstract. 
1) There are $n$ points -- 20 or 30, doesn't matter, They have coordinates - $(x_{i}, y_{i}, z_{i})$
2) I build $n \times n$ matrix of squared distances between each of them, check the wiki link for more details
3) It's been proved that the rank of such matrix is _less than or equal_ to space dimention + 2, which is $3+2=5$ in our case (3D space)
4) My matrix's rank is _exactly_ 5
What conclusions can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, had to search on the topic for a while. Something concrete had been found in an old, but frequently cited alticle.

*Theorem 6* there states:

> All the null vectors of $D$ are also null vectors of $F$, and they
>   satisfy $e^Tx_i = 0$. $F$ always has $s$ as a further null vector. If
>   $rank(D) = r$ then the dimensionulity of $D$ is:
>
> $(i)$ $r-1$ iff $e^TD^-e\neq0$, in which case the generating points
>   lie on the surface of a hypersphere, or
>
> $(ii)$ $r-2$ iff $e^TD^-e=0$, in which case the generating points
>   cannot lie on the surface of a hypersphere and $D^-e$ is a further
>   independent null vector of $F$.

...where $D$  is a EDM (Euclidean distance matrix) – real symmetric $n \times n$
matrix with elements $-\frac{1}{2}d_{ij}^2$ and with zero diagonal; the dimensionality of $D$ is the dimension of the space containing the
points that generate $D$; further details can be found in the original article.
(*Gower, J. C.*, [**Properties of Euclidean and non-Euclidean distance matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(85)90187-9), Linear Algebra Appl. 67, 81-97 (1985). [ZBL0569.15016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0569.15016).)

So, seemingly Wikipedia was not precise enough – *general position* in the case means "general" in terms of hypersphere. In other words, $rank(D) = r + 1$, if and only if the points generating $D$ lie on the relative boundary of an $r$-dimensional hypersphere.